# How do I use TypeScript with a Redux store with generic items?

Tags: typescript, redux

Say I have many different modals that I use in an application that have different structures
For example:

Modal 1

```
{
  id: 'modal1',
  validationKey: 'modal1Validation',
  data: {
    name: '',
    age: 54,
  },
}
```

Modal 2

```
{
  id: 'modal2',
  validationKey: 'modal2Validation',
  data: {
    approved: true,
    address: '',
  },
}
```

Before TypeScript I had the Redux store setup like this:

```
{
  ui: {
    modal: {}, // Load one of many modals into this property
  },
}
```

Are the only options to either:

Setup a Union with many different types

```
type Modal = Modal1 | Modal2 | Modal3 // ..etc
```

Or:

Setup modals to have a key for each modal

```
{
  ui: {
    modals: {
     Modal1: {
       id: 'modal1',
       validationKey: 'modal1Validation',
       data: {
         name: '',
         age: 54,
       },
     }
     Modal2: {
       id: 'modal2',
       validationKey: 'modal2Validation',
       data: {
         approved: true,
         address: '',
       },
     }
   }
}
```

Is there another clever way to do this with Generic Types?